# How do you type != when touch typing?

Tags: keyboard, touch-typing

Somehow I can't figure out a efficient way to type != (on a US keyboard).

- right pinky on shift + left pinky on !, then right pinky on =: long way for right pinky
- left pinky on shift, left ring finger on !, then right pinky on =: strange finger situation in left hand
- right pinky on shift + left pinky on !, then right middle (or ring)  finger on =: right hand has to move right/left a long way

All of this feels unnatural. How do you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like left pinky on `shift` + left middle finger on `!`, then right pinky on `=`.

!=!=!=!=!=!=!=!=!=!=

There, I just did it ten times and I'm not even *slightly* tired!

Comment: Don't you feel like your left pinky is gonna come off any second? :)

Comment: @RafaelReiter: It's not uncomfortable when I use the left middle finger. If I use the left ring finger then yes, the pinky feels bad.

Comment: @RafaelReiter: Are you coming from an AZERTY keyboard? Maybe it's just that I'm used to US QWERTY, but typing != on AZERTY looks even worse to me.